# Heroku Returned a H10 Error for Python App Deployment

Tags: python, heroku

I'm trying to deploy a python app on heroku, but heroku returned a H10 error. Here is my code python code:

```
import os
import requests
import random
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask_cors import CORS
from system.backend.data import Data
from system.backend.folder import Folder
from system.wallet.data_pool import DataPool
from system.wallet.exchange import Exchange
from system.pubsub import PubSub

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, resources={ r'/*': { 'origins': 'http://localhost:8080' } })
data = Data()
data_pool = DataPool()
folder = Folder(data)
pubsub = PubSub(data, data_pool)

@app.route('/')
def default():
    return 'Welcome to mypython app'

@app.route('/main')
def route_mainn():
    return jsonify(data.to_json())

@app.route('/main/range')
def route_main_range():
    start = int(request.args.get('start'))
    end = int(request.args.get('end'))

    return jsonify(data.to_json()[::-1][start:end])

@app.route('/main/datalength')
def route_main_datalength():
    return jsonify(len(data.length))

@app.route('/myapp/data')
def route_myapp_data():
    app_data = data_pool.app_data()
    exchange_data.append(Exchange.reward_exchange(folder).to_json())
    data.add_data(exchange_data)
    folder = data.length[-1]
    pubsub.broadcast_folder(folder)
    data_pool.clear_data_exchange(data)

    return jsonify(data.to_json())

@app.route('/folder/exchange', methods=['POST'])
def route_folder_exchange():
    exchange_data = request.get_json()
    exchange = data_pool.existing_exchange(folder.address)

    if exchange:
        exchange.update(
            folder,
            exchange_data['recipient'],
            exchange_data['sender']
        )
    else:
        exchange = Exchange(
            folder,
            exchange_data['recipient'],
            exchange_data['sender']
        )

    pubsub.broadcast_exchange(exchange)
    data_pool.set_exchange(exchange)
    
    return jsonify(exchange.to_json())

@app.route('/folder/info')
def route_folder_info():
    return jsonify({'address': folder.address, 'data': folder.balance})

@app.route('/known-addresses')
def route_known_addresses():
    known_addresses = set()

    for data in main.length:
        for exchange in main.data:
            exchange['output'].keys()

            known_addresses.update(exchange['output'].keys())
        
    return jsonify(list(known_addresses))

@app.route('/exchange')
def route_exchanges():
    return jsonify(exchange_pool.exchange_data())

ROOT_PORT = 8080
PORT = ROOT_PORT

if os.environ.get('PEER') == 'True':
    PORT = random.randint(8081, 9000)

    result = requests.get(f'http://localhost:{ROOT_PORT}/main')
    print(f'result.json(): {result.json()}')
    result_main = Data.from_json(result.json())

    try:
        data.replace_length(result_data.length)
        print('\n -- Successfully synchronized the local data')
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'\n -- Error synchronizing: {e}')

if os.environ.get('SEED_DATA') == 'True':
    for i in range(10):
        main.add_folder([
            Exchange(Folder(), Folder().address, random.randint(500, 1000)).to_json(),
            Exchange(Folder(), Folder().address, random.randint(500, 1000)).to_json()
        ])

    for i in range(3):
        data_pool.set_exchange(
            Exchange(Folder(), Folder().address, random.randint(500, 1000))
        )


app.run(port=PORT)
```

I also made a worker.py file with the code as follows:

```
import os

import redis
from rq import Worker, Queue, Connection

listen = ['high', 'default', 'low']

redis_url = os.getenv('REDIS_URL', 'redis://localhost:8080')

conn = redis.from_url(redis_url)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Connection(conn):
        worker = Worker(map(Queue, listen))
        worker.work()
```

The mac terminal recommended to use waitress for python deployment, but I'm not sure on how to implement waitress within the code shown on the above.

Answer (score 0):

To use `waitress`:

Just do `pip install waitress`

And add this snippet:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from waitress import serve
    serve(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=8000)
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I've tried doing so, but the heroku deployment still didn't work. Not sure what went wrong, but the codes to my files are as shown on the above.

Comment: What logs are you getting?
heroku logs --tail